# How to handle object updating/management when managing a large number of those objects?

Tags: oop, object, styles

More specifically, should each object be handling their own updating and logic by referencing their manager and using it as a proxy to retrieve other objects, or should the manager of the objects be handling the updating and various managements that those objects require?

Thanks for any responses, in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific when asking a question. It seems you have a concrete structure of classes in mind (manager of objects and objects) but did not describe it at all.

Comment: What kind of updating? That is totally unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If an object would need the manager to update itself, to get maximum encapsulation the manger should update objects. That way, objects to not have to know the manager at all.

Comment: Alright, and just to confirm, this is to prevent coupling between the manager and objects, correct?

Comment: Yes. What I take from your question is that the (object) manager has to know about the objects. However, the objects do not have to know about the manager.